# req.user undefined in Express 4

Tags: node.js, session, express

I built an app that uses Oauth to authenticate with a third party Jawbone app. I'm attempting to pull `req.user.jawbone.token` from `req.user` in one of my routes; however, I'm getting an error stating that `req.user` is undefined. I had this working in express 3, but after upgrading to express 4 it's no longer working - which leads me to believe that my sessions aren't being stored properly.

Here are the relevant parts of my `app.js` configuration:

```
var passport        = require('passport');
var session         = require('express-session')
var MongoStore      = require('connect-mongo')({session: session});
require('./config/passport')(passport);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());


// passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());        // persistent login sessions
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: mongoUrl 
    }),
    secret: 'password',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true 
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this problem, the issue was due to my middleware being in the wrong order. I rearranged to the below and it's working properly

```
app.use(session({
    store: new MongoStore({
        url: mongoUrl 
    }),
    secret: 'password',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true 
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```